# Recovering lost worlds in minecraft 1.10

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I started playing minecraft 1.10 recently and when I logged in i couldn't find my other worlds from 1.9. I worked very hard on it. Can someone tell me how to recover my worlds. I'm about to cry right now.

Comment: Are the worlds still in `%appdata%\.minecraft\saves`? Do the worlds reappear if you downgrade to 1.9?

Comment: Are u using a legitimate version of minecraft? (no torrent or from an unofficial website)

Answer (score 1):

Check your .minecraft/saves folder. On Windows, this is C:\Users[username\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\saves, on Linux this is /home/[username]/.minecraft/saves. If this folder is empty, then you're out of luck and you won't be able to recover any worlds. If, however, this folder is not empty, and you see your world, you should check what files still exist. If the level.dat file exists, then your world's seed and metadata still exists. If the .mca files in the region folder exist, then the world's block data still exists, but if these .mca files are gone, then your world's block data is gone, sorry.